# How to automate testing in weka?

Tags: c#, neural-network, kinect, weka, backpropagation

My C# program generates both training and testing data. I need to use Back Propagation Neural Network/ Multilayer perceptron in Weka GUI for classification & testing. Currently I'm supplying the testing data manually.

As my C# program generates test data, this has to be supplied automatically to the Multilayer perceptron in the weka. This is a Kinect application written in C#.

Is there a solution for automatic testing of data using weka?.
So that my application works without my manual intervention.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is to link C# code with Weka(Java). For this, I found [CSharpJavaMerger.](http://csharpjavamerger.org/) But we need to get the source code of Weka which is in Java, use the merger software for converting and thus link it to C# code.

Answer (score 1):

Weka has a Java API that that can be used to access the majority of the features exposed in the GUI. Plenty of documentation is available on their website. A good starting point is this guide to [using WEKA in Java Code.](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code)

Comment: Thanks regarding Java API, But I'm looking for C# and weka linking.